# vb.net form display multiple pictures, but only one picture displayed

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I am using vb.net list of pictureboxs to display multiple images. But it only display the first  image on the form.

My code is as follows:

```
    Dim Pics As New List(Of PictureBox)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 6
        Pics.Add(New PictureBox)
        Pics(i).Image = Image.FromFile("D:\11.gif")
        Pics(i).Top = i * 300
        Pics(i).Left = i * 300
        Pics(i).Width = 1000
        Pics(i).Height = 1000
        Me.Controls.Add(Pics(i))
    Next
```

In my code, I use the same image for all the 6 pictureboxs for test purpose. Is there anything wrong in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought, try setting width and height to 10, rather than 1000 and see what happens. Also, just be aware that these will be lined up diagonally from each other since you're shivting the top and left by 300 each time

Comment: Thanks Dan Drews, yes it is because of the alignment of the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `top` and `left` correctly.
try like this

```
   Pics.Add(New PictureBox)
   Pics(i).Image = Image.FromFile("D:\11.gif")
   Pics(i).Top = 10
   Pics(i).Left = 100 + (i * 100)
   Pics(i).Width = 100
   Pics(i).Height = 1000
   Me.Controls.Add(Pics(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have them in one line set Pics(i).Top = 300 "Then all pictures wil be horizontally"
"Then you will see all your picture boxes"
Or change Pics(i).Left = i * 150 to Pics(i).Left = 150 to get them all vertically.

The rest of the settings you need to change how you would like it.

```
Dim Pics As New List(Of PictureBox)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 6
        Pics.Add(New PictureBox)
        Pics(i).Image = Image.FromFile("D:\11.gif")
        Pics(i).Top = 300
        Pics(i).Left = i * 150
        Pics(i).Width = 100
        Pics(i).Height = 100
        Me.Controls.Add(Pics(i))
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks Creator, after I changed the setting of picture location, the problem solved.